# Can I use LIKE with an SQL variable?

Tags: sql, sybase

I have a query which looks something like:

```
select * from Table1 where name like '%ASD%'
```

I want to change it so that I can do something of this sort:

```
declare @name1 varchar(255)
select @name1 = 'dfg'
select * from Table1 where name like @name1
```

How should I achieve that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 
WHERE name LIKE '%' + @name1 + '%'
```

And `SET @name1 = 'dfg'` instead of `SELECT @name1 = 'dfg'`

Answer (score 1):

Use `SET` to assign a value to `@name1`, and be sure to set it to a desired search string (you generally see this as starting with a percentage sign, ending with one, or both):

```
set @name1 = '%dfg%'
```